# Vertical scrollbar is not working properly in html table

Tags: html, css

I need to set scroll for tbody if number of records will be more that time I view the records by using scroll bar.
For that I have used  vertical scrollbar for the tbody of the table. Scrollbar is working correctly in that case that all
column values(tbody) are coming under the single th column.
How to resolve this one? In this sample I have used css for tbody

```
tbody {
    height: calc(100vh - 340px);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your css class. this will work.

```
table ,tr td{
    border:1px solid red
}
tbody {
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    overflow:auto;
      height: calc(100vh - 360px);
}
thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )
}
table {
    width:400px;
}
```

updated js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/vinothsm92/pL1wqaj1/12/

Answer (score 2):

Remove one line from your css

```
tbody {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;//<--- Remove this line
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: As u said , I removed the css line . But it is not working

Comment: That's strange..., I just did in your fiddle. It is working there.

Comment: :@Vky: Scroll bar is not visible here.

Comment: Hi Vky, I have used the tbody style as you mentioned. Butl it is not displaying  scrollbar

Comment: And check this image now i have tried code in my local also, it is showing well with scrollbar also https://ibb.co/dcN3vk @M.Nithya

Answer (score 0):

Check with this :

```
tbody {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and remove

```
.scrollbar {
    height: 450px;
    overflow-y: auto; // Remove this line
}
```